# Ldap with ssl - WebSecurityConfig - java

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to use Ldap with SSL in my application. I'm using Appache Directory Studio to configure local connection. I tested connection in ADS and connection via SSL was estabilished succesfully, but i still have an error when i'm trying to login in my web application:

> Reason: simple bind failed: localhost:10636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: localhost:10636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake]

I'm using Spring-boot with spring security dependency.
here is my WebSecurityConfig class (it worked fine without ssl - i changed port to ssl and it stopped working...).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth

                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return  new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldaps://localhost:10636/"), "dc=springframework,dc=org");
    }

}
```